# Grails application profiling and performance tuning

Tags: performance, tomcat, grails, profiling

I'm currently having some performance issues with a Grails application running on Tomcat. During single page loads, I'm seeing fairly high CPU usage on the java process (around 20%), and I worry that this won't scale well.

I've looked at both Java Melody as well as the Grails Profiler plugin. However, these tools only seem to tell me what I already know -- which pages are loading more slowly than others.

I've also checked the number of connections to MySQL, and although there are quite a lot of queries, they seem to be executing almost instantly. Also, the MySQL process never shows up in top as using any meaningful CPU time, so I don't believe this is the source of the slowdown.

What I need to know is what methods or functions within my code are taking the longest time to run, so that I can evaluate them to see if they can be rewritten. So far, I've tried manually disabling certain portions of pages to test the load times. But it would be much easier if there were a tool that could help point me to the problematic code. Do such tools exist?

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions, PSI Probe might be worth a try: http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/

Comment: Also notice that you will face differences between dev and prod, since in development mode the reloading mechanism makes difference.

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend SpringSource InSight with tc server

http://www.springsource.org/insight

Answer (score 2):

You should not do performance testing in development mode (if you want to test production mode performance).

It's recommended to do performance testing in the appserver container you will be using for production (for example Tomcat).

If you really want to do quick performance testing, you can use the "grails prod run-war" command to do it. In that case you will have to add Grails JVM parameters to BuildConfig.groovy file

```
grails.tomcat.jvmArgs = ["-server", "-noverify", "-Xms512m", "-Xmx1024m", "-XX:PermSize=96m", "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m", "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"]
```

Start Grails in production mode with this command

```
grails prod run-war
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with my grails applications on tomcat.
So I went back to jetty - it seems to work better with jetty.

According to the new gails release infos, they fixed some tomcat issues, therefore a project upgrade could also fix your problem.

- http://grails.org/doc/2.1.3/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew21
- http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/